# What element of $\pi_2(S^2)$ do rational functions represent?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Take a rational function of a single complex variable.  View it as a continuous function from the Riemann sphere to itself.  Is there a nice way to compute which element of $\pi_2(S^2)$ this corresponds to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the cardinality of the preimage of a generic point, because generically the local degree of a complex analytic function is always +1.  If the rational function is $a(x)/b(x)$, then the number of solutions in $x$ to $a(x)/b(x) = y$ for generic $y$ is $\max(\deg a,\deg b)$.

Comment: Does this extends somehow to the quaternionic projective line?